# Create a time-variable DC power source

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, dc, dc-dc-converter, buck

For some reason, I need a time-variable DC power source that changes its value according to time. I need this change of value to be controllable.

I'll put it this way:
Say I have a 12 V DC power source like a car battery.
At some point I need this value to be changed to 11 V, then to 9 V, etc. to 0 V, and then start the cycle backwards from 0 to 1 V, then it increases to reach 12 V. This process should be time-controlled and time-based.

I am somehow familiar with buck converters, and I know they step down the supplied voltage, but I want this step down and then backward cycle of reaching up the supplied voltage to be time-controlled. I need to be able to control the whole cycle of this time-variable DC source.

Does such a circuit exist?
And if yes what are those circuits called?

I didn't specify any info about power or current, but if this is a problem then I guess the example I presented gives some hints: 12 V source power varying to 0 V, then cycling back from 0 to 12 V.
Efficiency needs to be as high as possible.

Comment: If the circuitry requiring this type of voltage input is high-impedance then you could write a simple program to drive a DAC to generate any arbitrary voltage. You could also write the code such that you take serial commands and drive it on-demand. If this will not work for you, then see [Arbitrary Waveform Generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary_waveform_generator).

Comment: There is a special term for time varying DC. It is called AC. If the waveform ramps up and down in linear fashion and is fixed in period, this is actually a low frequency triangle wave. Depending on what you want it for there are a lot of ways to generate it. You could create a low-voltage replica using a microcontroller DAC, then play it into a class D amplifier, for example.

Comment: By time controlled do you mean the power is changed in constant time increments, like AC? Is it a stepped (e.g. 1V to 2V) or continuous (e.g. sinusoidal) waveform? Can you post an example voltage vs time plot to make it more clear?

Comment: @sherrellbc I am not looking for a waveform generator! If I was I would clearly say it. I want a Time-Variable DC "Power Source" not a "Waveform Generator" , thank you so much.

Comment: @mkeith Well I am aware of the existence of AC power sources! Thanks for the hint. What I asked for was a DC Time-Variable Controllable Power source, so I can control it's value in the whole cycle time. Thank you so much.

Comment: @pikafu you are awesome! Yes I want it stepped like tiny steps vs time periods, and these tiny steps timing and value should be controlled by some means like a microcontroller or something. Thank you so much for your contribution and caring :-).

Comment: @Billo, Perhaps you did not consider the waveform generated could be a variable DC value. The point of an *arbitrary function generator* is that you may generate any waveform you like - even a constant DC type. Or, in your case, a constant DC value that varies over time in a predefined manner.

Comment: @sherrellbc thank you very much for this info. Now I know what you mean, buy I think even in this case the waveform generator is not capable of being a source power. So a class D amplifier must be taken into consideration in this situation right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want a power supply that can be controlled externally. Fortunately, these exist, and they are called programmable power supplies. You can connect a laptop to them and send them commands using MATLAB or another scripting language through a GPIB interface. For example check out [these power supplies](http://www.keithley.com/products/dcac/highspeedpower/programmablesingle), and [this GPIB cable](http://sine.ni.com/nips/cds/view/p/lang/en/nid/201586).

The company I work at uses a lot of programmable instruments combined with MATLAB to automate hardware tests.

Comment: I checked the links @pikafu yes this is somehow similar to what I want. But the example I presented is clear I think. I have the voltage "steady" source all I want is a circuit that would vary it with time like explained previously. Thanks for your answer

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. In that case I don't have the expertise to recommend a solution now. I will do some research and update my answer if I find anything new!

Comment: Update: http://www.electronics-lab.com/projects/power/020/ shows how to build a microcontroller controlled power supply. However as mkeith pointed out, it doesn't go all the way to 0V. I recommend searching for "microcontroller controlled power supply" and see what you get.

Comment: Answer was accepted for the update link in the comment. It's very useful @pikafu Thank you for everything you did. If you figure out further solutions I will appreciate it so much :-).

Answer (score 0):

You could use an SMPS with external feedback, and modify the feedback setpoint to adjust the output voltage. Typically the external feedback is a resistor divider that divides the output voltage down to the reference voltage (when output voltage is at the correct setpoint). However this won't support using an output voltage less than the reference.

You could control a DAC to make the 0-12V control signal (at low current), then drive an output stage to increase the available drive current. An emitter follower would be pretty simple (and being NPN avoids thermal runaway), though the DAC will need to drive about 0.7V higher to account for the Vbe voltage drop. Or you could use an opamp driving a FET, using negative feedback to ensure the output voltage matches the DAC output.

Comment: Emitter follower is a linear circuit. OP said as efficient as possible, so that would not qualify. The SMPS idea is better, but it is usually not possible to ramp it down to zero.

Comment: Can you provide some links for the schematic design ? And what type is that "output stage" after creating the DAC signal ?@MarkU

Comment: @Billo the output stage MarkU is suggesting is a BJT current gain stage which will provide the necessary current for your load. You can read about it here: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electronic/emitfol.html#c1

Comment: @pikafu Man you are awesome! I deeply admire this effort that you're doing. You've clarified enough about the power stage that Marku is talking about, but still I need a design for the circuit that does the variable part. Thank you so much

Comment: @Billo, maybe this would suit your needs:
http://www.hameg.com/0.271.0.html

Comment: Thank you. Yes this is close to what I am looking for. Except that I want to make one of these guys :-) so a schematic would be of a great help. I think I'll google arbitrary waveform power sources. Thank you @mkeith